# Tunnel over SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, tunnel

I have a VPS server running CentOS 6.5 and a also client running CentOS 6.5

I'm trying to make a tunnel connection over SSH protocol.

I use -v option to debug, I cant find any problem but i cant make a tunnel. Also please let me know if you see any security problem in debug.

```
ssh -vfN pmcode@198.23.xxx.xxx -p 3032 -L 8182:127.0.0.1:22

[root@localhost ~]# ssh -vfN pmcode@198.23.xxx.xxx -p 3032 -L 8182:127.0.0.1:22
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 198.23.xxx.xxx [198.23.xxx.xxx] port 3032.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '[198.23.xxx.xxx]:3032' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pmcode@198.23.xxx.xxx's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:8182 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:22
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 8182.
bind: Address already in use
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8182.
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 8182
Could not request local forwarding.
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 8182. 
bind: Address already in use
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8182.
bind: Address already in use
```

That means you already have some process bound to port 8182 on the local loopback.

Probably one of your other tries. Read

```
$ man netstat
```

for one of several ways to find out which process is the culprit.

If you want to bind more than one tunnels to the local loopback, you could bind to other port numbers *or* you could bind to other ip addresses. As `lo` should have a netmask of `255.0.0.0` any address starting with `127.` will work.

```
$ ssh -vfN pmcode@192.0.2.245 -p 3032 -L 127.0.0.2:8182:127.0.0.1:22
```

---

> Also please let me know if you see any security problem in debug.

Well it's not a problem for your ssh, but you linked your OpenSSH to an OpenSSL that is vulnerable to heartbleed (OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips). If you've linked any other programs that *do* use the TLS protocol implementation of it, it might be advisable to patch it and renew your key material.

Comment: There is not other program to listen the port, just SSH, but every time i change the port to a new one that is not listening (i used ` netstat -tulpn`), please replace IP with "xxx" –

Comment: @hamidreza66 feel free to edit, but please follow [RFC5737](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3152478/383793) instead of "xxx" when using example ip addresses.